# Как сравнить значения полей в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пытаюсь выделить аномальные отклонения некоторых плана от факта.

Задача - оставить на рассмотрение только те строки, в которых план расходится с фактом на величину, превышающую 20% от факта.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\file.xlsx',
                   index_col = None)
df = df[df['fact'].notnull() | df['plan'].notnull()]

df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).set_index('Code')
df['fact'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['plan'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df1 = df.copy()
for i in df.index:
    lower = df.loc[i, 'fact']*0.8
    higher = df.loc[i, 'fact']*1.2
    current = df.loc[i, 'plan']
    if current > lower & current < higher
        df1.drop(i)

df1.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\file2.xlsx')
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/proj/asd.py", line 17, in <module>
        if current > lower & current < higher:
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Пробовал и так:

```
...
for i in df.index:
    first = False
    second = False
    if current < higher:
        first = True
    if current > lower:
        second = True
    if first and second:
        df1.drop(i)
...
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/proj/asd.py", line 22, in <module>
    if current < higher:
  File "C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Не могу решить эту проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in df.index:
    lower = df.loc[i, 'fact']*0.8
    higher = df.loc[i, 'fact']*1.2
    current = df.loc[i, 'plan']
    if current > lower & current < higher
        df1.drop(i)
```

- Обычно всегда можно обойтись без перебора `DataFrame`, совершая действия сразу со всей колонкой. Это и понятнее и эффективнее.
- Вы в своём коде всё-равно в итоге работаете не с отдельными числами, а с `Pandas series`, поэтому у вас и выходит ошибка. Вы можете в принципе взять первое число из серии (оно же и единственное), но, повторюсь, лучше обойтись вообще без перебора по индексу.

Правильный код может выглядеть так:

```
lower = df['fact']*0.8
higher = df['fact']*1.2
current = df['plan']
df1 = df.loc[(current <= lower) | (current >= higher)]
```

Обратите внимание на скобки в последней строке. Именно они чинят ошибку "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, вы очень сложно пытаетесь решить эту проблему.
я бы посоветовал сделать по-другому:

Исходные:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'plan':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'fact':[1.2, 2.4, 2.8, 4.1, 4.9]})
df1 = df.copy()
```

df1:

```
   plan  fact
0     1   1.2
1     2   2.4
2     3   2.8
3     4   4.1
4     5   4.9
```

Далее - обычное сравнение солбцами:

```
res = df[df1.pct_change(axis='columns')['fact'].ge(0.2) | np.isclose(df1.pct_change(axis='columns')['fact'], 0.2)]
```

Собственно, `res` получится:

```
   plan  fact
0     1   1.2
1     2   2.4
```